# How to annotate input file with values from multiple files using python

Tags: python

I have 400 tab-delimited text files with 6 million rows in each file. Below is the format of the files:

```
 ### input.txt 
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
ID1     str4    123     cond1   1
ID1     str1    234     cond1   0
ID1     str2    567     cond1   0
ID1     str3    789     cond1   1


### file1.txt
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
ID2     str1    235     cond1   0
ID2     str2    567     cond2   3
ID2     str3    789     cond1   3
ID2     str4    123     cond2   0

### file2.txt
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
ID3     str1    235     cond1   0
ID3     str2    567     cond2   4
ID3     str3    789     cond1   1

file3.txt, file4.txt.....
```

I would need to add values in column1 from the files file1..filen to column6 in input.txt file by using conditions:

```
1. columns 2 and 3 as key 
2. If the key is found in files1...filen and if column5>=2 add the value   
from col1 to col6 in the input file.
```

Desired output is to annotate each row in input.txt file with value in column 1
from file1..filen if the key is found.

```
Output.txt
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6
ID1     str4    123    cond1    1    
ID1     str1    234    cond1    0    
ID1     str2    567    cond1    0       ID2,ID3,
ID1     str3    789    cond1    1       ID2,
```

I do have an awk solution. However, the problem is that the code is very slow as it has to iterate each key in input.txt through 400 files with 6 million rows in each file i.e.400*6mi= 2.4 billion rows. This takes several hours to few days.  Could someone suggest a better solution in python by reducing the iteration times and improving the processing time.

Comment: I would suggest you to use DB, load your data in it and then run the desired  update.

Comment: My first quick idea: It sounds like you take a key from Input.txt and compare it through all rows in all files. So if it appears only once in row 2, you scan the other 6mio for nothing. If you take the row from the fileN.txt and compare it to Input.txt, you will only run until you find the key and you can then go on with the next row in fileN. Depending on the data that might quite a bit of time.